# How to access template template parameters in type alias?

Tags: c++11, template-templates, type-alias

Is it possible to use template template arguments inside a type alias? For example is it possible to write a type alias similar to this:

```
#include "tuple"

template<
    template<class... Types> class Container,
    class... Types
> using another_tuple = std::tuple<Types...>;

another_tuple<std::tuple<int>> t;
```

which, when given e.g. std::tuple, uses its Types for something else? Both GCC and Clang mention class templates in their errors, how do I avoid needing a class template? If I remove all ...s GCC error changes to:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
another_tuple<std::tuple<int>> t;
                            ^
```

which I don't understand. Container itself doesn't have to be a template but I couldn't figure out how to use std::tuple in its place.

Update based on n.m.s answer, the correct format is:

```
another_tuple<std::tuple, int> t;
```

and similarly even when the types are in a container:

```
using types = std::tuple<int, char>;
another_tuple<std::tuple, types> t;
```

which has a bit of redundant code but should be good enough.

Comment: Holdong it wrong http://ideone.com/RbJrhq usage example.

Comment: Not the way you did above.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};

template<template<class...>class Z, class types>
struct apply_types;
template<template<class...>class Z, class types>
using apply_types_t=type_t<apply_types<Z,types>>;
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct apply_types<Z,types<Ts...>>:tag<Z<Ts...>> {};

template<template<class...>class M, class types>
struct map;
template<template<class...>class M, class types>
using map_t=type_t<map<M,types>>;
template<template<class...>class M, class...Ts>
struct map<M,types<Ts...>>:types<M<Ts>...>{};

template<class...lists>
struct concat:types<>{};
template<class...lists>
using concat_t=type_t<concat<lists...>>;
template<class...lhs, class...rhs>
struct concat<types<lhs...>,types<rhs...>>:
  types<lhs...,rhs...>
{};
template<class types>
struct concat<types>:
  types
{};
template<class types, class...more_types>
struct concat<types, more_types...>:
  concat<types, concat_t<more_types...>>
{};

template<class A, template<class...>class C, class T, class F>
struct condition:std::conditional<C<A>{}, T, F>{};

template<template<class...>class Z, class... T>
struct bind_1st_n {
  template<class...Ts>
  using apply=Z<T..., Ts...>;
};

template<class Tok, class list, class A>
struct replace_helper:
  condition<A, bind_1st_n<std::is_same, Tok>::template apply, list, types<A>>
{};

template<class list, class if_this, class then_these>
struct replace:
  concat<
    map_t<
      bind_1st_n<replace_helper,if_this, then_these>::template apply,
      list
    >
  >
{};

struct placeholder {};

template<class T> struct get_args;
template<class T> using get_args_t=type_t<get_args<T>>;
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct get_args<Z<Ts...>>:types<Ts...> {};

template<template<class...>class Z, class types>
struct apply;
template<template<class...>class Z, class types>
using apply_t=type_t<apply<Z,types>>;


template< class Container >
using another_tuple = apply_t< std::tuple, get_args_t<Container> >;
```

and if you want the list to expand with int in front, and double at the end:

```
template< class Container >
using another_tuple = apply_t< std::tuple,
  replace_t<
    types<int, placeholder, double>,
    placeholder,
    get_args_t<Container>
  >
>;
```

which builds the list to apply, then applies it in two steps.

None of this code has been compiled.